# Creating a polygonal spatial data frame from a feature geometry attribute

Tags: mysql, r, r-sp, r-maptools

I have a data frame that I pulled from a MySQL database that has a feature geometry attribute. For example, here's one record's value for the geom attribute:

```
'POLYGON((-113.583914 33.786816,-113.58412 33.787018,-113.58412 33.786816,-113.583914 33.786816))'
```

All features in the table are polygons.

I have been searching but cannot find a clean way to create a spatial data frame from these coordinate strings.

Comment: On the narrow question of how to create a `SpatialPolygons` object from that WKT string, see the function `readWKT()` in the **rgeos** package.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien you should make that an answer

Comment: Thank you, I was able to find ample documentation now knowing that the geometry strings are called WKT. For example: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/58322/plotting-large-numbers-of-objects-on-a-chart-using-r-and-wkt-format/58539#58539

Comment: @damian Good to hear. Thanks for coming back to post the link to that useful answer that you found.